# Problem with custom css in angular project

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

First I'm french so sorry if I make mistakes.
Second I'm new in angular so please describe me your answers as much as possible. Thanks

So I want to import a custom css file in my angular project but the problem is when I put the path to the file in the .ts file and in the .html file, The whole custom and component style is overwrites.

I have no error on my terminal.

Do you have some solutions for this little problem ?

Thanks to those who will respond

Comment: Please elaborate on what "the whole style is overwrites" means.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your css is only related to the component you use styles **or**
   styleUrls (only in the .ts). See [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-overview)
2. If your .css is for all the app you should add in the styles array
   in [angular.json](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration)
3. NOTE: Perhafs you want to make a [tutorial of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial)

When we ork with material-angular, we need take account that material work using intensivaly [cdk-overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview). (e.g. a calendar use cdk-overlay).

This mean that create a "component" **outside** your component -really outside of the main-app- (you can see if use F12 in your navigator). This makes that the .css you use in your component not can "reach" the "component". For this you need include your .css in your "styles.css" or "styles.scss" -that are common to all the app-. Generally all this components has a property "panelClass" (or similar) you can use a addicional selector if only want to change in a component, e.g. in a calendar

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker" >
    <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <!--see that you use panelClass="custom"-->
  <mat-datepicker #picker panelClass="custom"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

And in styles.css

```
.custom .mat-calendar-body-label
{
  color:red;
}
```

see [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzu4u5?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-custom-icon-example.html)

Comment: Hello,
In fact in my project I have a component of angular material and I have made a separate form. Then I put the form (in html and css and js ) in respective files of the angular project. Then I put the paths for the js and css files. My html is displayed, but when I put MY css it overwrites everything but part of the calendar code (the angular component), so there is a problem but I don't know what. But, what I understand from your answer is that I am in case 2 and I have to put my css in the angular.json file.

Comment: @PhilibertGentien, material work hard using [cdk-overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview). (e.g. a calendar use cdk-overlay). I updated the answer to include this case