# How to add a class to dynamically rendered angular material components

Tags: angular, angular-material

With relation to the [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74059011/how-to-target-elements-through-directives-which-are-rendered-by-angular-material) where we were trying to target a dynamically rendered angular material component class `cdk-overlay-container` through class selector(which is not possible) using a directive, the actual use case being to add a class(eg `foobar`) to material component. For example it may be `cdk-overlay-container` or any other class inside the component.

1. The initial though was to add a directive which would target the
   elements in material component but that doesn't seem to be possible - tested it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hoverdirective-nodv2q?file=src/app/EventhoverDirective.ts), have tried using attribute selectors like role and tabindex(with/without values) and pre-defined attribute like `mat-menu-item` nothing seems to work
2. I am open to suggestions, if there was any other way to achieve the same.

Update 1: Even before thinking of adding the directive which adds a class, the initial thought was to make use of DOM API which would select any element(by class/attribute) and add the intended class to it. But since that is not the angular way of doing things because of security concerns involved in it, i didn't want to go through that road.

Update 2: In simple terms the goal is to select any elements/child elements which are rendered using angular material components and add a class to it. One suggestion below is to add panel class that is helpful but it doesn't solve the problem of adding class to child elements.

Comment: Generally all the components that use cdk-overlay has a property `panelClass` (change this property is the adecuate way to do it), so you can use as selector in styles.css this class, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74053501/problem-with-custom-css-in-angular-project/74053685#74053685)

Answer (score 1):

> The actual use case being to add a class(eg `foobar`) to material component eg) `cdk-overlay-container` or any other class inside the component.

By wanting to add a class to some component/element, your hidden goal is to override the styling of some material components.

Using `mat-menu` as the example, we have these options:

1. Apply style to material component **globally**. This will apply to all instances of `mat-menu`.
2. Apply style to material component **locally**. This will only apply to the current `mat-menu`.
3. Bonus.

### 1. Applying style to material component globally:

**example.component.html**

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

**style.css (root style.css file)**

```css
// We can directly target the class/element you want to override
.mat-menu-item {
  color: red;
}
```

---

### 2. Apply style to material component locally:

**example.component.html**

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

**example.component.css**

```css
// We need to use ng-deep to reach into the element. 
.mat-menu-item::ng-deep {
  color: red;
}
```

---

### 3. Bonus:

If you want to conditionally apply styling, you can do:

**example.component.html**

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [class]="true ? 'my-menu' : '' ">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

**style.css (root style.css file)**

```css
// We only apply style to if the component has .my-menu class
.my-menu .mat-menu-item {
  color: red;
}
```

You can also do this locally *if and only if* the target element is not part of the overlay (`cdk-overlay-container`). That's because `cdk-overlay-container` is rendered along side the app component which is usually the top level container.

When we add a class and supply the styling to `mat-menu` locally, the CSS doesn't recognize that because `cdk-overlay-container` isn't inside the `mat-menu` with `my-menu` class.

[image]

The official doc explains:

> @Input('class')
> panelClass: string
>
> This method takes classes set on the host mat-menu element and applies them on the menu template that displays in the overlay container. Otherwise, it's difficult to style the containing menu from outside the component.

Comment: Thanks for the taking time to explain about targeting components to override/add styles, i would like to correct the assumption about the end goal, it is not to override styling because it is not, the reason to add class was because a third party library was rendering the data differently based on the class. So it was never my intention to target the class for updating styles.

Comment: @TheViralGriffin It's more or less the same thing. Your goal is still making a component renders in a specific way. You just need to target the third-party component's CSS and make it renders to your need. It's less messy than trying to add a class to a component and its dynamically added children. Imagine a poor soul in the future looking at the code and wondering why they have a piece of feature that does nothing but just to add a class to a component?

Comment: like i said earlier my goal is not to change styles, if that was the goal i would have used ng-deep or any other alternative, my goal is to just add a class.